# Error: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: clientObject

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to get list count from my custom list for current user. But the error: ("Error: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: clientObject") is being thrown. First part of the code where i have to get properties of current user works fine. I think PopulateEmployeeHeader(currentUser) is causing the error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    // Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadUserData, 'SP.UserProfiles.js'); 
    $('#errorBase').hide();  
  });
  var userProfileProperties;
  var user;
  function loadUserData(){

    //Get Current Context   
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    //Get Instance of People Manager Class
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    //Get properties of the current user
    userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties()

    clientContext.load(userProfileProperties);

    //Execute the Query.
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);

  }

  function onSuccess() { 

    var employeePhoto =userProfileProperties.get_pictureUrl();
    PopulateEmployeeHeader(userProfileProperties.get_displayName());

    if(employeePhoto !== undefined && employeePhoto !== "" && employeePhoto !== null)
    {
        $('#employeePicture').attr('src', userProfileProperties.get_pictureUrl());
        }
        else
        { 
        $('results').innerHTML = "Picture does not exist in User Profiles list. Please upload your picture.";       
        }  
    }  
  function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert("Error: " + args.get_message());
  }

var oEmployee;
function PopulateEmployeeHeader(currentUser)
{   
//  var queryListItem = '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="j2ur"/><Value Type="User">'+currentUser+'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>';
    var queryListItem='<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="j2ur" />'+currentUser+'</Eq><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="j2ur" />'+
    +'</IsNotNull></And></Where></Query></View>';
        var siteUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host+'/';
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oEmployees = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Accounts');

    var myquery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    myquery.set_viewXml(queryListItem);
    this.oEmployee= oEmployees.getItems(myquery);

    clientContext.load(oEmployee);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onEmployeeSucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onEmployeeFailed)
 );
}

function onEmployeeSucceeded(sender, args) {

alert(oEmployee.get_count());
}

function onEmployeeFailed(sender, args) {

 alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +'\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it without SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadUserData, 'SP.UserProfiles.js'); ? Just 
$(document).ready(function(){       
   loadUserData
    $('#errorBase').hide();  
  });

Comment: That didn't work either:( What i ended up doing was re-factoring the code. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up rewriting the code. The following works like a charm:)

```
var web;
var user;
var context;
var userdisplayName;
$(document).ready(function(){
context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = context.get_web();
user = web.get_currentUser();
context.load(user);
context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
});

function onSuccess()
{
var employeePhoto =userProfileProperties.get_pictureUrl();
if(employeePhoto !== undefined && employeePhoto !== "" && employeePhoto !== null)
    {
        $('#employeePicture').attr('src', userProfileProperties.get_pictureUrl());
        }
        else
        { 
        $('results').innerHTML = "Picture does not exist in User Profiles list. Please upload your picture.";       
        }  
    }  

PopulateHeader(user.get_title());
}
function onFail()
{
  alert("Error: " + args.get_message());
}

function PopulateHeader(username)
{
var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Accounts');
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'j2ur\'/>' + '<Value Type=\'User\'>'+ username+'</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);        
    context.load(collListItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var empNumber=oListItem.get_item('_x0065_os0');
        listItemInfo += "Title : " + oListItem.get_item('Title') + "<br/>";
        listItemInfo += "Project : " + oListItem.get_item('_x0069_i43') + "<br/>";
        listItemInfo += "EmployeeNumber : " + oListItem.get_item('_x0065_os0') + "<br/>";


    }
$('#employeeNumber').html(empNumber);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Is there a general fix for this problem? Or could I post my code?